Obtener button clicado form PHP
tengo un formulario con dos botones, y quiero que cuando se haga el action se envie tambien el value del boton clickado.
<form method="post" action="<?= $this->url->href('TaskCreationController', 'show2', array('project_id' => $project['id'])) ?>" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="task-form-container">
        <div class="task-form-main-column">
            <div class="space"> </div>
            
                   <button type="submit" class="btn2 fifth" name="btSubmit" value="Casa">Casa</button> 
                   <button type="submit" class="btn2 fifth" name="btSubmit" value="Edificio">Edificio</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

Al hacer submit se llama a la función show2() y desde esta he probado obtener el valor de diferentes maneras:
$test= $_POST['btSubmit'];
$test2= $_GET["btSubmit"];(Probado por probar, ya que envio los datos por POST)
echo $_POST["btSubmit"];
en todas obtengo valor de NULL. Como puedo obtener el valor "Casa" si hago click en ese boton?
EDIT:
    public function show2(array $values = array(), array $errors = array())
    {
        if( isset($_POST['btSubmit']) ){ echo $_POST["btSubmit"]; }

        $project = $this->getProject();
        $swimlanesList = $this->swimlaneModel->getList($project['id'], false, true);
        

        $values = $this->hook->merge('controller:task:form:default', $values, array('default_values' => $values));
        $values = $this->hook->merge('controller:task-creation:form:default', $values, array('default_values' => $values));

        $this->response->html($this->template->render('task_creation/show', array(
            'project' => $project,
            'errors' => $errors,
            'values' => $values + array('project_id' => $project['id'], $values['title']),
            'columns_list' => $this->columnModel->getList($project['id']),
            'users_list' => $this->projectUserRoleModel->getAssignableUsersList($project['id'], true, false, $project['is_private'] == 1),
            'categories_list' => $this->categoryModel->getList($project['id']),
            'swimlanes_list' => $swimlanesList,
        )));
    }


Hola. No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el código con el que  manejas la recepción de datos, una vez el formulario se ha enviado? En esa parte deberías tener algo del tipo: if( isset($_POST['btSubmit']) ){ echo $_POST["btSubmit"]; } Creo que ves  NULL inicialmente porque no evalúas previamente si el formulario ha sido enviado.

En el código simplemente intento obtener el valor. El formulario si se envia, lo he comprobado previamente añadiendo <input type="text" name="txtInput"> . Y de esa forma con echo $_POST["txtInput"] si que obtengo el valor, pero en cambio el del button no.

Yo he hecho una prueba simple, cambiando esto <?= $this->url->href('TaskCreationController', 'show2', array('project_id' => $project['id'])) ?> por un #, dado que no tengo contexto de lo que todo eso produce y me funciona perfectamente. Pero he puesto lo que te indico más arriba, o sea, un isset. Si no te funciona, es un problema contextual, debido a lo que están produciendo esas variables que escapan a nuestro control. Debes depurar tu código. De todos modos, deberías mostrar el manejo que haces en tu función `show2()'.

Añadida funcion show2(). Si es un input text si lo recibo sin problemas, el problema es al ser un button y querer coger el value de ese button clickado.

¿Si pones un var_dump($_POST); en el isset, dentro de show2, qué muestra? Especifica también si usas algún framework. Lo digo porque no me suena mucho esa forma de pasar parámetros que tienes en el action del formulario.

en el isset si lo pongo no me aparece nada. He puesto el var_dump($_POST); fuera de isset y, recibo txtInput que es el campo texto que he incluido para pruebas, pero nada del button.
Utilizo un proyecto de codigo libre llamado KanBoard, en principio no se utiliza ningún framework.

A ver si he entendido...

en todas obtengo valor de NULL. Como puedo obtener el valor "Casa" si hago click en ese botón?

Es que eso no se maneja así, o por lo menos no en una manera normal y practica.
Debes tener un único botón de submit pero solo para enviar el formulario y tener controles o inputs para el resto de cosas. Para mi lo más practico sería con radios.
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';

        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $lugar = $_POST['lugar'];

        echo $nombre.' has elegido '.$lugar.' para vivir.';
    } 
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <br>
    casa => <input type="radio" name="lugar" value="Casa">
    <br>
    Edificio => <input type="radio" name="lugar" value="Edificio">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="ENVIAR">
</form>

// Resultado
/*
Array
(
    [nombre] => Juan Pérez 
    [lugar] => Edificio
)
Juan Pérez has elegido Edificio para vivir.
Juan Pérez has elegido Casa para vivir.

Los dos radios envían diferentes values con el mismo name. O sea, puede elegir una sola cosa y no las dos.
Si lo quieres hacer un poco mejor, puedes darle la forma de botones a esos radios, luego con JS les pones la función de submit y eliminas el botón de enviar del formulario.
PD: Una vez el formulario se ha enviado con el value de casa o edificio puedes ejecutar la función de show2() pero ya con el parámetro correctamente definido.

Toda la razón, no lo estaba haciendo de manera optima. No habia caido en utilizar radios. Muchas gracias!

Me alegra que te funcionara, y como te dije, si al final le quieres poner botones, dales el estilo con CSS. Acá tienes una guía. A mi me gusta darles ese estilo de botones pero les pongo mi toque personal
